# Pass success failure status from controller to Blade/view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How can we pass success failure status with some message from the controller to the Blade file?

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()->with('failure', 'File uploaded Successfully');
}
```

**Blade/View**

```
@if (session()->has('failure'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
         {{ session()->has('failure') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data ?

Comment: use `session()->get('failure')` in your if statement

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    return redirect()->back()->with('failure', 'File uploaded failed!');
}
```

Blade:

```
@if (session()->has('failure'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
         {{ session()->get('failure') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller's function add this line

```
session()->flash('success', 'File uploaded Successfully');
```

and in view put this code

```
@if (session()->has('failure'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
     {{ session()->get('failure') }}
</div>@endif
```

Comment: Getting error when using flash on request.
RuntimeException
Session store not set on request.

Comment: now check i have updated the answer, use session() instead of request.